# parse xml and display in label ios swift 3

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing

Now i want to parse the data from my database. And it was in xml format. But i have done the parse and get the response as 200 as success. But i want to show the data in my label.Its like a kind of quiz app.

so my screen will look like this :

```
  **QUESTION LABEL

  ANSWER 1
  ANSWER 2
  ANSWER 3
  ANSWER 4**
```

Now how can i do like this:

I have IBOUTLET Labels :

```
questionlabel
answer1 label
answer2 label
answer3 label
answer4 label
```

My code :

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let headers = [
            "content-type": "application/xml",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "55edcaba-0256-2114-00bc-6b46f288c962"
        ]

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://example.need.com/quiz")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse)


            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()

    }
```

My xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<map>
    <data>
        <list>
            <item>
                <map>
                    <answerChoice>
                        <list>
                            <item>option1</item>
                            <item>option2</item>
                            <item>option3</item>
                            <item>option4</item>
                        </list>
                    </answerChoice>
                    <assessmentID>ajhsdja</assessmentID>
                    <explanation>Explanations.</explanation>
                    <question>Which is ur name?</question>
                    <questionType>multiple</questionType>
                    <correctAnswer>option1</correctAnswer>
                </map>
            </item>
            <item>
                 <map>
                    <answerChoice>
                        <list>
                            <item>option1</item>
                            <item>option2</item>
                            <item>option3</item>
                            <item>option4</item>
                        </list>
                    </answerChoice>
                    <assessmentID>ajhsdja</assessmentID>
                    <explanation>Explanations.</explanation>
                    <question>Which is ur name?</question>
                    <questionType>multiple</questionType>
                    <correctAnswer>option1</correctAnswer>
                </map>
            </item>
            <item>
                <map>
                    <answerChoice>
                        <list>
                            <item>option1</item>
                            <item>option2</item>
                            <item>option3</item>
                            <item>option4</item>
                        </list>
                    </answerChoice>
                    <assessmentID>ajhsdja</assessmentID>
                    <explanation>Explanations.</explanation>
                    <question>Which is ur name?</question>
                    <questionType>multiple</questionType>
                    <correctAnswer>option1</correctAnswer>
                </map>
            </item>
            <item>
                <map>
                    <answerChoice>
                        <list>
                            <item>option1</item>
                            <item>option2</item>
                            <item>option3</item>
                            <item>option4</item>
                        </list>
                    </answerChoice>
                    <assessmentID>ajhsdja</assessmentID>
                    <explanation>Explanations.</explanation>
                    <question>Which is ur name?</question>
                    <questionType>multiple</questionType>
                    <correctAnswer>option1</correctAnswer>
                </map>
            </item>
            <item>
                <map>
                    <answerChoice>
                        <list>
                            <item>option1</item>
                            <item>option2</item>
                            <item>option3</item>
                            <item>option4</item>
                        </list>
                    </answerChoice>
                    <assessmentID>ajhsdja</assessmentID>
                    <explanation>Explanations.</explanation>
                    <question>Which is ur name?</question>
                    <questionType>multiple</questionType>
                    <correctAnswer>option1</correctAnswer>
                </map>
            </item>
        </list>
    </data>
</map>
```

Please help me out. I need to show the question, answers with one one question, First i dont know how to get the data from my response and save in array or should i need to pass directly ??

Please give me some code explain..Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's your attempt to parse the XML?

Comment: in my code i am getting the response as 200 ok in my console for this code `let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse)`.. does its not a kind of parsner ?. i get the code from postman

Comment: No. All you've done so far is retrieve the data that contains the XML document.

Comment: if i need to get xml parsenr. how ca i do with my data ?? and url ??

Comment: Do some research on using the `XMLParser` class.